# How to enable IPV6 on c-lightning in docker properly?

Tags: core-lightning

Helping to run v0.10.1 node for a client, who wants to enable IPV6.
Now listconfigs say:

`"bind-addr": "0.0.0.0:9735"`

`"autolisten": true`

Reading this: https://lightning.readthedocs.io/lightningd-config.5.html?highlight=bind-dir

It's unclear to me. Is the way to enable IPV6 to put another bind-addr for it and have:

`"bind-addr": "0.0.0.0:9735"`

`"bind-addr": "[MYIPV6ADDRESS]:9735"`

Or can there only be one bind-addr?
The installation is docker on VPS.
So, the host has many other inet6 addresses from all that, and seems that should not set

`"bind-addr": "::9735"`

Comment: Why do you need to bind two addresses? This type of address is used only internally

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to leave the IP empty, like this:

`bind-addr=:9735`

will bind on both IPv4 and IPv6.

> An empty ‘IPADDRESS’ is a special value meaning bind to IPv4 and/or
> IPv6 on all interfaces, ‘0.0.0.0’ means bind to all IPv4 interfaces,
> ‘::’ means ‘bind to all IPv6 interfaces’.